Incremental Backup/Archiving with no file deletion on Windows
I am running on Windows 10.
I would like to set up a scheduled back-up that would be the equivalent of copy-pasting the source folder onto the backup location, thus copying over any new files, any modified files and not overwriting any files that already exist within the backup (compression would also be welcome).
Now what I am talking about is very similar to an incremental backup, the key difference being that I would like to periodically empty my source folder of files I no longer use, without them ever being deleted from the backup. If I understand correctly, even if I enable infinite version retention on an incremental backup, I would have to remember the exact date I deleted a file in order to access a previous version of the backup with the file still in it.
I hope I was clear enough, and that the answer is not that painfully obvious...
I tried looking for videos online explaining different types of backups, but from what I understand, none I've seen fulfill my specific need. I installed Veam Agent before realizing that it also does not do exactly what I wanted it to do, in that, I create backup 1, I delete a file, I create backup 2, I open backup 2 and the file is not there. I would need to open backup 1 in order to see the deleted file. Now imagine that, but with 1000 backups, with no idea when exactly the file was deleted. That is horrible.
UPDATE
I have discovered FreeFileSync as an option for what I would like to do, I will update this thread if I manage to get it up and running. Any other, cleaner solutions are welcome, since this program does look a bit clunky.

Based on your description two programs come to my mind: git  and restic backup. Both are open source. BTW asking for software recommendations is off topic here.

Thank you! Also, which tag are you reffering to when you say that it's off-topic here? Or are you referring to stackoverflow in general?

Yes, software recommendations are off topic on Stackoverflow in general, I assume because there is no definitive answer based on facts which increases the chance of flame wars. For questions on which software to use there is https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/
